# High CPL resolved temporarily by NFS restart

Tags: linux, nfs4

CentOS 6.9

I've got an NFS (v4) file server whose exports started becoming very slow to respond on clients today. While this is happening, the exported volumes are not slow on the server itself.

atop shows very high CPL values (> 100). Otherwise nothing looks out of the ordinary.

If I restart nfs (`service nfs restart`), the CPL values quickly start dropping and the volumes become responsive again on the clients. However after 2 or 3 minutes, CPL values start climbing again.

dmesg doesn't show anything other than some messages when I restart nfs.

/var/log/messages doesn't show anything that looks relevant

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

```
   CPL  CPU load information.
        This  line contains the load average figures reflecting the number of threads that are available to run on a CPU (i.e. part of the runqueue) or that are wait‐
        ing for disk I/O. These figures are averaged over 1 (`avg1'), 5 (`avg5') and 15 (`avg15') minutes.
        Furthermore the number of context switches (`csw'), the number of serviced interrupts (`intr') and the number of available CPUs are shown.
```

I think the important take away from this `waiting for disk I/O`. I'm betting a client is trying to do something funky with the disks and it's causing a slow down for the rest of the clients. Have you checked to see what kind of network bandwidth is being used? Is the link fully saturated?

Comment: Sometmies this server slows because of high disk usage, as reported by atop and iostat. However in this case atop isn't reporting any other high values. Disk usage is low and jumps up when I restart nfs. Network load is very low.

Comment: Interestingly, last night the server's NFS shares started responding normally again even though CPL was still high, 100+. Currently CPL is about 45 and the shares are responding with no delay, except for one that currently has high disk usage that's responding with slight delay..